# Splash/Throw Drink At

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Let's say the context is a guy and and girl at a restaurant.  Then, they had an argument.  Then, the girl picked up a glass of beverage (full) and then made one jerking movement of the glass at the guy, causing the content of the glass to leave the glass and hit the guy in the face.  The glass itself never left the girl's hand.  I came up with two possible sentences to describe the situation:

> 1. She ***splashed*** the drink at him.
> 2. She ***threw*** the drink at him.

I have a feeling that "*throw*" is not the correct verb to use, since there was no overhead movement of the arm.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Overhead movement of the arm? There's nothing wrong with throwing sidearm.

Comment: @J.R. is right, in that you can throw sidearm or underhand; nothing about "throw" implies overhead.  Also don't forget that "throw" is a verb with many modal and metaphorical uses: you can throw up, throw out, throw away, throw down, throw in the towel, throw around an idea; something can be a throwback or an overthrow...so the meaning of "throw" can be very fluid!

Answer (score 2):

You could use *throw*, but it's more ambiguous. If someone "throws a drink" at me, it's not clear if it's merely the contents of the glass that are thrown, or if the glass is thrown, too. But surrounding context could clarify that:

> *We argued for some time, and then I called her a moron, and that really made her angry. She picked up her drink and threw it at me! My shirt got soaked, and the olive hit me right in the forehead. Then she slammed the glass back down on the table and stomped out of the restaurant. All eyes were on me, so I sheepishly said, "It's just like her to leave me with the check."*

or, if the glass did leave her hand:

> *We argued for some time, and then I called her a moron, and that really made her angry. She picked up her drink and threw it at me! Luckily, I ducked. My shirt got a little wet, but the glass made it all the way to the wall – I was surprised it didn't break. Then she stomped out of the restaurant. All eyes were on me, so I picked up the glass and sheepishly said, "Good thing she throws like a girl."*

Answer (score 1):

For liquid (especially drink/water), it's 'splash'. I mean that *is the word*!

A typical example  on [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/splash_1?q=splash)

> *He splashed cold water on his face.*

On [NBCMiami](http://www.nbcmiami.com/news/local/Miss-Universe-New-Friends-Countless-Dresses-and-1-Crown-289599561.html) I found that Miss Universe contestants ***splashed*** water at the photographer.

'Throw water' looks a bit *off* to me.

---

Good thing to know: *throw water* is possible but then, it becomes a part of [an idiom.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+cold+water+on)

> Throw cold water on something - *to criticize or stop something that some people are enthusiastic about*

Answer (score 0):

She [dashed her drink](https://books.google.com/books?id=QVAmAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=dashed%20a%20drink%20in%20his%20face&source=bl&ots=6JImfrvrdQ&sig=29R64X8qL2jCKLwDupuFntXc1OQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LrrYVOXVLOqwsASXr4KIDQ&ved=0CHAQ6AEwEA#v=onepage&q=dashed%20a%20drink%20in%20his%20face&f=false) in his face.  A [modern usage](http://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/news/greater-manchester-news/watch-lammars-northern-quarter-attack-7506440) with video:

> Members of XXXX's entourage shoved Ms YYYYY to the floor, and a drink
>   was dashed in her friend ZZZZZ ZZZZ-ZZZZ's face in the melee,
>   drawing bouncers to the scene.